# Why does this LCS algorithm produce multiple duplicates of each element?

Tags: java, algorithm, lcs

My alg&dat book introduces this algorithm for length of longest common subsequence:

```
public static int LCSLength (int[] X, int[] Y, int i, int j) {
    if(i==0 || j ==0) {
    return 0;
        }
    else if (X[i-1]==Y[j-1]) {
        return 1+LCSLength(X,Y,i-1,j-1);
        }
    else if(LCSLength(X,Y,i-1,j)>LCSLength(X,Y,i,j-1)){
        return LCSLength(X,Y,i-1,j);
        }
    else {return LCSLength(X,Y,i,j-1);}
}
public static int LCSWIndex(int[] X, int[] Y) {     
    return LCSLength(X, Y, X.length, Y.length);
}
```

I am trying to modify this alg to generate the LCS itself instead of just its length:

```
    public List<Integer> lcs;
    public List<Integer> LCS (int[] X, int[] Y, int i, int j) {
       if(i==0 || j ==0) {
           return lcs;
       }
       else if (X[i-1]==Y[j-1]) {
           lcs.add(X[i-1]);
           return LCS(X,Y,i-1,j-1);
       }
       else if(LCS(X,Y,i-1,j).size()>LCS(X,Y,i,j-1).size()){
           return LCS(X,Y,i-1,j);
       }
       else {return LCS(X,Y,i,j-1);}
       
   }
   public static List<Integer> LCSWIndex(int[] X, int[] Y) {   
       LCSClass s = new LCSClass();
       s.lcs = new ArrayList<>();
       return s.LCS(X, Y, X.length, Y.length);
   }
```

This does appear to correctly identify which elements belong to the LCS, but generates multiple duplicates of them each. In other words, if I use `stream().distinct()` on it I kind of get the correct result. Why does this happen and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem description belies a misunderstanding of the concept of 'longest common subsequence'.

**There is no such thing as THE longest common subsequence.**

There is such a thing as **a** longest common subsequence. Take as example `{1,2,5}` and `{2, 1, 5}`. The length of the longest common subsequence is clear and there can only be one answer to that question. It's 2. But what is this longest common subsequence? There is no one answer. `{1, 5}` is correct. So is `{2, 5}`. So which one should your code produce? The 'leftmost' one? The smallest one? An arbitrary one? All of them?

### Okay, so how do I solve this?

Do what programmers do: Debug your code.

Come up with a good example; one where you observe that your program doesn't emit what you think it should. That's how you find bugs: Find a case where the code acts differently from what you expected it to do.

Then, slice the problem into pieces: Be the computer, step through the code line by line and figure out what it should be doing. Then, run the program. Use a debugger (or add a bunch of System.out.println statements) to emit the intermediate bits (for example, at the start of every call to the LCS method, print the `lcs` list as it is right now, and what i and j are, for example). Compare to what you worked out on paper.

Where the two differ? That's where the problem lies.